# SharePoint 2010 plus VS 2010 32-bit & Sql Server 32-bit on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I got a Windows 64-bit Home premium laptop and I want to install SharePoint 2010 on that.

Also, can I install VS 2010 32-bit & Sql Server 2005 32-bit software's and work with SharePoint 2010 64-bit app?

I mean will that work properly?

Please advise me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From all the articles I have read so far, Sharepoint 2010 cannot be installed in Windows 7 Home premium for various reasons (one being Windows Authentication not available in Windows 7 Home Premium). You will need Professional or above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it is not true that we cannot install Windows 7 Home premium and I just installed Sharepoint 2010 in my laptop but it requires sql server 2008 64-bit. Also, you can use Basic Authentication to work with your sites (which I am doing now). Follow this link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx